# Accept Date and Time ("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss") as valid input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble when validating datetime, I have a property in my class and I want this property to receive the value of a date and the time too. Example: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.

This is my Model:

```
public class Period
{
    [Display(Name = "Begin Date:")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss}")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Format")]
    public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
}
```

This is the cshtml:

```
    @model WebSample.Models.Period

    <form action="Index">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeginDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @data_type = "datetime" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BeginDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

When I text `11/09/2018` it doesn't complain anything but when texting `11/09/2018 11:51:00` it fires `The field Begin Date must be a date`.

I would like to accept inputs with the format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Also you may consider reducing your Tags. This question looks very specific and you have a lot of tags that are not relevant.

Comment: Thank you, I've added more details to the questions and removed unnecessary tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeginDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @data_type = "datetime" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BeginDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: Thank you.
I forgot to translate part of the question. Edited.

Comment: `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]` try with this.